# How do I perform unit tests involving redis, socket.io, and nodejs/express?

Tags: unit-testing, express, redis, socket.io

I am currently running into problems attempting to create unit tests that involve the interaction of socket.io, redis, and express.  I'm looking for strategies on how to best mock these interactions.  For example, I am using socket.io-client to mock the connection/behavior of socket.io to my express server but then when I add a test to check if redis is storing the proper information from socket.io I find myself needing to also mock socket.io in the redis unit test which in turn means I need to mock the express server.  This leads to the point where it seems like I'm rewriting another server just to unit test the actual server I am trying to test.

Has anyone had to do this before? If so could you point me to resources (google/stack overflow are slim in results)?

Comment: unit tests has nothing to do with redis socketio or express etc, its simply testing of any unit / module / function.

Comment: Are you saying you write unit tests to check if redis is working correctly?

Comment: I guess I meant "integration test".  I want to make sure socket.io and redis are interacting correctly based on a request coming in from the express server.

Answer (score 0):

What part of the application are you trying to test?
One way is encapsulating the socket connection in a `socket.service.js` file.

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

class SocketService {
  constructor(server) {
    this.socket = socketIO(server);
  }

  initialize() {
    this.socket.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('connected')

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnected')
      });

      socket.on('register', registerHandler);

      socket.on('update', updateHandler);
    });
  }
}
```

Your unit test could be that it registers agains a mock `server`, and that it calls the `initialize` method.

If you are trying to test all of them working together, then you are talking about integration and e2e testing.